# Ranking with multiple ocurrence of ties in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ranking, rank, ranking-functions

I need to rank my df by some columns. Have a look at the print below

[image]

The lines need to be ranked from 1 to 20 by the column `df['pontos_na_rodada']`

If we issue some ties - which will occur - they have to be resolved by the highest value in column `df['saldo_gols']`. Then if the tie persist resolve it again by the column `df['gols_feitos']` and lastly if we still have ties resolve it by column `df['Red Cards']` and `df['Yellow Cards']` where for these columns the lower value is the best.

Can someone give me a hand?

Example of the data in the image:

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_dict of        league_season  league_round  fixture_id  team.id  resultado  \
50885           2020           1.0      327986      118        3.0   
46622           2020           1.0      327992      119        3.0   
50863           2020           1.0      327986      120        0.0   
60003           2020           1.0      327987      121        1.0   
46637           2020           1.0      327991      123        3.0   
46774           2020           1.0      327990      124        0.0   
55991           2020           1.0      327994      126        3.0   
46700           2020           1.0      327985      127        0.0   
46730           2020           1.0      327988      128        1.0   
46652           2020           1.0      327991      129        0.0   
46758           2020           1.0      327990      130        3.0   
50908           2020           1.0      327989      131        1.0   
60024           2020           1.0      327987      133        1.0   
46684           2020           1.0      327993      134        3.0   
50931           2020           1.0      327989      144        1.0   
46606           2020           1.0      327992      147        0.0   
55970           2020           1.0      327994      151        0.0   
46668           2020           1.0      327993      154        0.0   
46743           2020           1.0      327988      794        1.0   
46714           2020           1.0      327985     1062        3.0   

       gols_feitos  saldo_gols  Red Cards  Yellow Cards  pontos_na_rodada  \
50885          2.0         1.0        0.0           3.0               3.0   
46622          1.0         1.0        0.0           4.0               3.0   
50863          1.0        -1.0        1.0           2.0               0.0   
60003          1.0         0.0        0.0           1.0               1.0   
46637          3.0         1.0        0.0           3.0               3.0   
46774          0.0        -1.0        0.0           3.0               0.0   
55991          3.0         3.0        0.0           NaN               3.0   
46700          0.0        -1.0        0.0           3.0               0.0   
46730          1.0         0.0        0.0           NaN               1.0   
46652          2.0        -1.0        0.0           3.0               0.0   
46758          1.0         1.0        0.0           2.0               3.0   
50908          0.0         0.0        0.0           2.0               1.0   
60024          1.0         0.0        0.0           1.0               1.0   
46684          2.0         2.0        0.0           2.0               3.0   
50931          0.0         0.0        0.0           NaN               1.0   
46606          0.0        -1.0        0.0           3.0               0.0   
55970          0.0        -3.0        0.0           3.0               0.0   
46668          0.0        -2.0        1.0           3.0               0.0   
46743          1.0         0.0        0.0           1.0               1.0   
46714          1.0         1.0        0.0           2.0               3.0   

       rank  
50885   NaN  
46622   NaN  
50863   NaN  
60003   NaN  
46637   NaN  
46774   NaN  
55991   NaN  
46700   NaN  
46730   NaN  
46652   NaN  
46758   NaN  
50908   NaN  
60024   NaN  
46684   NaN  
50931   NaN  
46606   NaN  
55970   NaN  
46668   NaN  
46743   NaN  
46714   NaN  >
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible form of your input (ideally code for a `DataFrame`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out an answer to show here:

```
df['rank'] = np.nan
df['Red Cards'] = df['Red Cards']*-1
df['Yellow Cards'] = df['Yellow Cards']*-1
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(by = ['league_season','league_round','pontos_na_rodada',\
                                  'saldo_gols','gols_feitos','Red Cards','Yellow Cards'])\
                                  .groupby(['league_season','league_round']).cumcount(ascending=False)+1
df[(df['league_round']==10) & (df['league_season']==2020)].sort_values(by = 'rank')
```

The result:

```
       league_season  league_round  fixture_id  team.id  resultado  \
49809           2020          10.0      328084      119        0.0   
50032           2020          10.0      328076      133        3.0   
49919           2020          10.0      328079     1062        3.0   
49671           2020          10.0      328078      126        1.0   
49964           2020          10.0      328077      121        1.0   
49855           2020          10.0      328083      127        0.0   
49648           2020          10.0      328078      128        1.0   
49694           2020          10.0      328080      130        1.0   
49740           2020          10.0      328075      124        3.0   
49832           2020          10.0      328083      129        3.0   
49899           2020          10.0      328081      144        3.0   
49717           2020          10.0      328080      154        1.0   
49876           2020          10.0      328081      118        0.0   
49602           2020          10.0      328082      134        3.0   
49987           2020          10.0      328077      123        1.0   
49763           2020          10.0      328075      131        0.0   
50009           2020          10.0      328076      120        0.0   
49786           2020          10.0      328084      151        3.0   
49625           2020          10.0      328082      147        0.0   
49942           2020          10.0      328079      794        0.0   

       gols_feitos  saldo_gols  Red Cards  Yellow Cards  pontos_na_rodada  \
49809          0.0        -1.0       -0.0          -3.0              20.0   
50032          3.0         1.0       -0.0          -2.0              18.0   
49919          2.0         1.0       -0.0          -1.0              18.0   
49671          2.0         0.0       -0.0          -2.0              18.0   
49964          2.0         0.0       -1.0          -3.0              18.0   
49855          0.0        -2.0       -0.0           NaN              17.0   
49648          2.0         0.0       -0.0          -3.0              15.0   
49694          1.0         0.0       -1.0          -1.0              15.0   
49740          2.0         1.0       -1.0          -2.0              14.0   
49832          2.0         2.0       -0.0          -1.0              13.0   
49899          1.0         1.0       -0.0          -2.0              13.0   
49717          1.0         0.0       -1.0          -2.0              12.0   
49876          0.0        -1.0       -1.0          -2.0              12.0   
49602          1.0         1.0       -0.0          -4.0              11.0   
49987          2.0         0.0       -1.0          -3.0              11.0   
49763          1.0        -1.0       -0.0          -4.0              10.0   
50009          2.0        -1.0       -0.0          -2.0               9.0   
49786          1.0         1.0       -1.0          -4.0               8.0   
49625          0.0        -1.0       -1.0          -2.0               8.0   
49942          1.0        -1.0       -0.0          -1.0               7.0   

       rank  
49809     1  
50032     2  
49919     3  
49671     4  
49964     5  
49855     6  
49648     7  
49694     8  
49740     9  
49832    10  
49899    11  
49717    12  
49876    13  
49602    14  
49987    15  
49763    16  
50009    17  
49786    18  
49625    19  
49942    20
```